# authenticationManger method not present in spring security 6, Saml Config migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml

We are migrating our springboot application to springboot 3.x. In the latest version of springboot, i see the spring-security upgraded to version 6.

In this version `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is removed.

I have a SamlConfiguation class written on spring-boot 2. x. I have to define `SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter` and `SAMLProcessingFilter` beans.

These beans use `authenticationManager()` method from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class.

How do I define them using spring security 6?
i changed it to

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

but when i start the application call any api, i get the error
`10:20:55.995 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/cms-service/webapi].[dispatcherServlet].log() @175 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cms-service/webapi] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void doFilter(jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of interface jakarta.servlet.Filter. at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)`

here is my complete `SAMLSecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl.class, Environment.class, SAMLConfig.class})
@Order(2)
public class SAMLSecurityConfig {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SAMLSecurityConfig.class);

private static final String LOGIN = "/login";

private final SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

private final Environment environment;

private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;

private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
private  AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;
@Autowired
public SAMLSecurityConfig(SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl,
                          Environment environment, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher, AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) {
    this.samlUserDetailsServiceImpl = samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;
    this.environment = environment;
    this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    this.authenticationConfiguration = authenticationConfiguration;
}
@Autowired
public  SAMLConfig samlConfig;

public SAMLConfig config() {
    samlConfig.setEntity();
    return samlConfig;
}
// Initialization of OpenSAML library
@Bean
public static SAMLBootstrap samlBootstrap() {
    return new CustomSAMLBootStrap();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
    this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    this.backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
    this.backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
    this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
}

// Initialization of the velocity engine
@Bean
public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
    VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SimpleLog4JLogSystem");
    props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category", "velocity");
    props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "velocity");
    props.put("UTF-8", "UTF-8");
    props.put("resource.loader", "classpath");
    props.put("classpath.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    engine.init(props);
    return engine;
}

// XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
@Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
    return new StaticBasicParserPool();
}

@Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
    return new ParserPoolHolder();
}

// Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
}

// SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
// messages
@Bean
public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
    SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
    return samlAuthenticationProvider;
}

// Load Balancer Context Provider
@Bean
public SAMLContextProviderLB contextProvider() {
    SAMLContextProviderLB samlContextProviderLB = new SAMLContextProviderLB();
    samlContextProviderLB.setServerName(config().getSp().getServerName());
    samlContextProviderLB.setIncludeServerPortInRequestURL(false);
    samlContextProviderLB.setServerPort(config().getLb().getServerPort());
    samlContextProviderLB.setScheme(config().getLb().getScheme());
    samlContextProviderLB.setContextPath("/cms-service/webapi");
    return samlContextProviderLB;
}

// Logger for SAML messages and events
@Bean
public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
    return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
}

// SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumer hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
    WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl webSSOProfileConsumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    webSSOProfileConsumer.setResponseSkew(180);
    webSSOProfileConsumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(180);
    return webSSOProfileConsumer;
}

// SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOAssertionConsumer() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 ECP profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpProfile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
}

@Bean
public SingleLogoutProfile logoutProfile() {
    return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
}

/*
 * Central storage of cryptographic keys
 *
 * If your project does not require any keys you can replace the code below with:
 *    return new EmptyKeyManager();
 */
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(config().getKeyStore().getResource().getFile())) {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(fileInputStream, config().getKeyStore().getPass().toCharArray());
    } catch (IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Error reading keystore file", e);
    }

    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
    passwords.put(config().getKeyStore().getAlias(), config().getKeyStore().getPass());

    assert keyStore != null;
    return new JKSKeyManager(keyStore, passwords, config().getKeyStore().getAlias());
}


@Bean
public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
    WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
    webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
    return webSSOProfileOptions;
}

// Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
// properties file
@Bean
public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
    SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
    samlEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(webSSOprofile());
    samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
    httpClient().getState().clear();
    return samlEntryPoint;
}

// Setup advanced info about metadata
@Bean
public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true);
    extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
    extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
    extendedMetadata.setSslHostnameVerification(ALLOW_ALL.toString());
    return extendedMetadata;
}

// Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL());
    metadataGenerator.setEntityId(config().getSp().getEntityId());
    metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
    metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(true);
    metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
    return metadataGenerator;
}

// The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
// and presents SP metadata there
@Bean
public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
    return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
}

// Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
@Bean
public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
            new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL());
    return successRedirectHandler;
}

// Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
@Bean
public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
            new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    failureHandler.setUseForward(false);
    failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL());
    return failureHandler;
}

@Bean
public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
}

// Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
@Bean
public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    httpClient().getState().clear();
    return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
}

@Bean
public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
    return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
}

// Handler for successful logout
@Bean
public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
    SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new CustomSimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL());
    return successLogoutHandler;
}

// Logout handler terminating local session
@Bean
public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler =
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
    logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
    return logoutHandler;
}

// Filter processing incoming logout messages
// First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
// global logout
@Bean
public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
    return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
            logoutHandler());
}

// Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
// messages
@Bean
public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
    return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
            new LogoutHandler[]{logoutHandler()},
            new LogoutHandler[]{logoutHandler()});
}

// Bindings
private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
    final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile =
            new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
    artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
    return artifactResolutionProfile;
}

@Bean
public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
    return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
}

@Bean
public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
    return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
    return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
}

@Bean
public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
    return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
    return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
    return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}

// Processor
@Bean
public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
    Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();
    bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
    bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
    bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
    bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
    bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
    return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
}

/**
 * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
 *
 * @return Filter chain proxy
 */
@Bean
public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
    List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<>();
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
            samlEntryPoint()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
            samlLogoutFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
            metadataDisplayFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
            samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
    return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
}

/**
 * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
 * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
 * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
 *
 */
@Bean

public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

/**
 * Defines the web based security configuration.
 *
 * @param http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
 *
 */
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic(httpBasic-> httpBasic.authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint()));
    /*http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());*/
    /*http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/saml/**");*/
    http.csrf(csrf->csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .ignoringRequestMatchers("/saml/**"));

    http
            .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    /*http
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout"))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN);*/
    http.logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout"))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN));
    /*http
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable();*/
    http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable));
    /*http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN)
            .invalidSessionUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN);*/

    http.sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN)
            .invalidSessionUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN));
    /*http
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN);*/
    http.sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL() + LOGIN));
    /*http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation()
            .newSession();*/
    http.sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
            sessionManagement.sessionFixation().newSession());

    /*http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);*/
    http.sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER));

            permitEndpoints(http);
    http.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    return http.build();
}

/**
 * Sets a custom authentication provider.
 *
 * @param auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
 */
/*@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
}*/


private void permitEndpoints(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if (isSamlDisabled()) {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());
               // .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                //.anyRequest().authenticated();
    } else {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests ->
                        authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll());
        /*
                .requestMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();*/
    }
}

private boolean isSamlDisabled() {
    return Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(
            env -> (env.equalsIgnoreCase("samlDisabled")));
}

public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("in onAuthenticationSuccess");
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
                    cookie.setValue("");
                    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
        }
        if(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL().equalsIgnoreCase(this.getDefaultTargetUrl())) {
            URLBuilder builder = new URLBuilder(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            builder.setPath("/");
            builder.setFragment("/login?SSO="+ UserPolicy.AUTH_TYPE_SAML);
            builder.setPort(CmsUtil.getWebServerPort());
            this.setDefaultTargetUrl(builder.buildURL());
        }
        request.changeSessionId();
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}

public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    protected String defaultFailureUrl = null;

    public String getDefaultFailureUrl() {
        return defaultFailureUrl;
    }
    @Override
    public void setDefaultFailureUrl(String defaultFailureUrl) {
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl(defaultFailureUrl);
        this.defaultFailureUrl = defaultFailureUrl;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("in onAuthenticationFailure");
        if(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL().equalsIgnoreCase(this.getDefaultFailureUrl())) {
            URLBuilder builder = new URLBuilder(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            builder.setPath("/");
            builder.setFragment("/login?SSO="+ UserPolicy.AUTH_TYPE_SAML);
            builder.setPort(CmsUtil.getWebServerPort());
            this.setDefaultFailureUrl(builder.buildURL());
        }
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}

public class CustomSimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(config().getSp().getEntityBaseURL().equalsIgnoreCase(this.getDefaultTargetUrl())) {
            URLBuilder builder = new URLBuilder(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            builder.setPath("/");
            builder.setFragment("/login");
            builder.setPort(CmsUtil.getWebServerPort());
            this.setDefaultTargetUrl(builder.buildURL());
        }
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}


@Bean
@Qualifier("idp-keycloak")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate keycloakExtendedMetadataProvider(Environment env)
        throws MetadataProviderException {
    String idpKeycloakMetadataURL = env.getRequiredProperty("keycloak.auth-server-url") + "/protocol/saml/descriptor";
    HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
            this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpKeycloakMetadataURL);
    httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
            new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}
@Bean
@Qualifier("metadata")
public CachingMetadataManager metadata(List<MetadataProvider> providers) throws MetadataProviderException {
    providers.remove(0);
    return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
}
}
```

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare an `authenticationManager` `Bean` in security configuration class?

Something like this:

```
  @Autowired
  private  AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration; // or constructor injection depends on what you are using

      @Bean
      public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
      }
```

**UPDATE**: If you cannot do it with an method param, just use the above provided code.

Comment: but how can I use this in creating those SAML related beans? In older versions the authenticationManager does not take any parameters.

Comment: one sec, i will change a little bit the answer

Comment: i did it, can you try ?

Comment: any news, about this approach?

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing with your configuration. I'm still refactoring the configurations to work with spring-secuity 6. Will update if there are any issues.

Comment: For any questions ping me here

Comment: I refactored all the code to spring-security 6. But I see that javax.servlet in SAML MetadataGeneratorFilter is not compatible with jakarta.servelet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255194/discussion-between-manjosh-and-andrei-lisa).

Comment: sure let`s do it